# Infragistics UltraTextEditor changes font in Edit mode

Tags: c#, vb.net, infragistics

I have a Infragistics UltraTextEditor (v.18.2): I set the font property to "Consolas", "10pts" both in the "Appearance" and in the "Font" sections of the control's properties.

The UltraTextEditor *displays* correctly (i.e. with my font properties) its content, but when I *edit* the content, font is set to 9pts, which seems to be it's default. I (and my users) would like the font to stay set at 10pts, of course. Is there something I am missing?

Thanks in advance to anyone who will help

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is that you can avoid this by doing one of two things:

1. Set the UltraTextBox property of AlwaysInEditMode = True
2. Set the UltraTextBox property of TextRemderingMode = GDI

The change in spacing (between edit and non-edit mode) is caused by the underlying .NET TextBox, which was created before GDI+.  .NET uses GDI+ as it's native mechanism for drawing and the UltraTextBox uses GDI+ when displaying the UltraTextBox in non-edit mode.  When entering edit mode, the drawing mechanism changes to the old GDI, which causes a difference in spacing.

[Credit: Infragistics Community Forum](https://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/f/ultimate-ui-for-windows-forms/23812/why-does-font-spacing-change)